# Magento - Edit product price attribute and save

Tags: php, magento, product

I'm creating some customization to my product page. I've already implemented an API that check my company price service and edit the product page with the new information. Example: Product was registered with $50.00 and my logic at the price.phtml modify it to $90.00.

My problem is the addToCart logic. The product is added with the old value ($50.00) and not the new one ($90.00).

Can someone please detail everything I need to do adjust this problem?

I'm using the logic below to create custom attribute:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setData('product_custom_info', $customInfo);
```

It's possible to create something similar to this for product price?

Comment: This is happening because you have added your price to file but not saved in the database so magento has lot backend validation and always loads product details from database using product id while adding into cart. So possibly you can do it by creating a price update script and schedule it to run by cron. There wouldn't be any problem then.

Comment: Hi Laxman. The product price is modified depending on the user session. My API check some customer information and update the product price based on some attributed. So I don't want to change the product price at the dataBase. The idea is to change the price only on that particular session.

Comment: Well, in that case you will have to define some hooks those can dedicatedly look for activity like "add to cart", "get quote" etc and update the price in checkout/cart session (can deal with quote).

Comment: `checkout_cart_product_add_after
sales_quote_remove_item
checkout_cart_update_items_after`
These events can be used to update the price. Give a try. I would again say doing this way is not a good practice. Use customer groups and add group prices to your products which will automatically be managed by magento itself and i guess it will resolve your problem too.

Comment: Hi Laxman. I'm new on Magento and I'm not familiar with this event logic that you mentioned. Could you please explain where I can edit them and how I need to customize to adapt to my logic? Thx!!

Comment: Hello Bruno, These are just some events which magento triggers while adding item to cart, updating cart etc. So you just need to create your own module in local directory and define an observer for these events in config.xml of your module. In observer class, write a program to update price of items in cart quote.

Comment: Hi Laxman. I followed a tutorial to create everything that you explained but it's not working. I published this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112760/magento-customized-module-not-working). Can you help me on this please?

Comment: Hey Bruno, I have created a compressed module and its fully functional. I used your code snippets and assembled into a module. You might have any syntactical issue but its working. Please clone from here https://github.com/lapitspublic/TrediMarketplace_PriceUpdate.git