# Magento - Customized Module not working

Tags: php, magento

I'm creating a module to customize my products price when adding it to the cart but it's not working. I'm using the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` method.

Steps that I followed:

1) Create a XML (`TrediMarketplace_PriceUpdate`) at `/app/etc/modules` and it's already appearing at the Magento interface (`System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced`)

2) Create the config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <TrediMarketplace_PriceUpdate>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </TrediMarketplace_PriceUpdate>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <tredimarketplace_priceupdate>
                <class>TrediMarketplace_PriceUpdate_Model</class>
            </tredimarketplace_priceupdate>
        </models>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <tredimarketplace_priceupdate>
                        <class>tredimarketplace_priceupdate/observer</class>
                        <method>priceUpdate</method>                        
                    </tredimarketplace_priceupdate>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

The file is hosted at this path: `/app/code/local/TrediMarketplace/PriceUpdate`

3) Create the Observer.php:

```
<?php   
    class TrediMarketplace_PriceUpdate_Model_Observer{
        public function priceUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
            // Get the quote item
                $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
            // Ensure we have the parent item, if it has one
                $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
            // Load the custom price
                $price = "300.00";
            // Set the custom price
                $item->setCustomPrice($price);
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            // Enable super mode on the product.
                $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        }
    }
?>
```

The file is hosted at this path: `/app/code/local/TrediMarketplace/PriceUpdate/Model`

With this steps my expectations are that all products added to the cart appear with $300.00 (value that I fixed on my module) but this is not occurring.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is the full path of your 'config.xml' file ?

Comment: Hi Prateek. The full path of `config.xml` is: `/public_html/testes/app/code/local/TrediMarketplace/PriceUpdate/etc/config.xml`. The full path of `Observer` is: `/public_html/testes/app/code/local/TrediMarketplace/PriceUpdate/Model/Observer.php`

Comment: "Add to cart" functioning is default or did you change something in there ?

Comment: Default. The unique change that I made is at the "price.phtml" for tests in the product page.

Comment: Hi Prateek. If you have any clue on this, please let me know. Thx

Comment: I don't see any error in the code, and in a default installation, it should work. Either there is some minor typo that is not easy to see, or something related to caching. Did you check with enabling "Developer Mode" ?

Comment: Hmm..I've edited the `.htaccess` including at the last line this code: `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"`. Is that correct?

Comment: Add some intentional error in any file that is working right now, you'll know for sure.

Comment: I've created an log file when the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` occurs and it worked!!! The error must be at the `Observer.php` file for changing the price! Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have created a compressed module and its fully functional. I used your code snippets and assembled into a module. You might have any syntactical issue but its working. Please clone from here https://github.com/lapitspublic/TrediMarketplace_PriceUpdate.git

Comment: Hi Laxman, thx for your answer. I copied from your GitHub but it still now working =/.
[Example of product](http://tredi.com.br/testes/index.php/protecao-eletrica/placa-de-controle-para-altivar-1100-1100.html) at my test website.
When the product is added to the cart, the value does not change to "$300.00"

Comment: Can you just put `die('Stop! stop! right here.');` at beginning of your method in observer so that i can make sure pointer is going into right method.

Comment: need any assistance/troubleshooting please ping me at skype

Comment: Hi Laxman. I added you on skype and included `die('Stop! stop! right here.');` at the beginning of the observer. One more time, thx for your help

Comment: Hello Bruno, pointer is not going into your observer. your module may have conflict with some other modules like for same event there may be multiple observers but with conflicts. Today evening, i will talk to you over skype (IST).

Comment: Hi Laxman, I'm using the default template of Magento. After installation I didn't made any change. Do you think the default template may have some conflict with this module? Please, feel free to call me on skype anytime. Thx

Comment: I've created an log file when the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` occurs and it worked!!! The error must be at the `Observer.php` file for changing the price! Thx a lot